# Javascript Limitations of Google Apps Scripts WebApps?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

C'mon help me push the boundaries a little here...

Google [supports](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#code.gs) sticking your Javascript in an html file.
This guy [shows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1W1yTHcJduI) how to display images in a webapp done in a google script.
That guy [makes](https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/PNXbGo) `those images have s3x` (I mean, give me a better description here!)

Settings variables for the images residing in a Google Drive in the Code.gs and later trying to use them in the javascript file doesn't work. I get a blank screen.

Is this a limitation of Google or a Javascript knowledge limitation on my part?

This here is the code dot js where I map the two images.

[image: Code.gs]

This shows the html we see

[image: Page.html]

This is where the magic happen...

[image: Javascript.html]

the css....

[image: the css]

Comment: Kindly use text of the code and not images. See [mcve]

Comment: You are misunderstanding. Review [scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).

Comment: @TheMaster I've reviewed, and thank you by the way, but I missed your point. Tell it to me straight please.

Comment: First thing I noticed is that you never passed or saved then fetched the values of those variables. So it is expected to have nothing outputted. Try saving it as a property then use `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(clientSideFunctionToProcessReturnedData).someServerSideFunction() ` to get the value.

Comment: `htmlOutput.pictures=pictures`. But where is  the `pictures`  scriplet on the html file that you're evaluating, i.e., `Page.html`? Pay attention to [this part](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#apps_script_code_in_scriptlets)

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

You instantiated `pic1` and `pic2` in your Code.gs and is expecting to have those values when you are in your HTML/JavaScript file which is not totally the case.

#### Solution:

To pass values from server side to client side, use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). You can directly call `get_the_images` instead of instantiating it to variables then passing them. See sample code below on how values are passed from GS to your HTML/JavaScript.

#### Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page');
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function get_the_images() {
  // supposedly ID of said images (IDs for test purposes)
  return ['rxcmaiw_23jsu', 'qwejiasd23saf'];
}
```

#### Page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    value of pic1 id is:
    <span id="pic1">
    </span>
    </br>
    value of pic2 id is:
    <span id="pic2">
    </span>

    <?!= include('Javascript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Javascript.html:

```
<script>
  let span1 = document.querySelector('#pic1');
  let span2 = document.querySelector('#pic2');
  // call get_the_images function from Code.gs
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).get_the_images();

  function onSuccess(result){
    // result contains the return value of get_the_images
    var [pic1, pic2] = result;
    // at this point, pic1 and pic2 contains the ids
    // show them as images using your script
    // below just confirms the IDs if passed properly
    span1.innerHTML = pic1;
    span2.innerHTML = pic2;
  }
</script>
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run